# Getting/Setting SVG graphics size in html

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have SVG graphics (just text) between html `<body>` tags. I need the size of the images in inches. I tried `.getBoundingClientRect()`.  But different browsers (ie, firefox, safari and chrome) return different values (probably viewbox scale, not inches).

I have several of these SVG graphics. How can I fit them in the screen and keep ratio (same screen size, different SVG graphics different size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: change the viewbox attribute dynamic.